# tracking down Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I often get this error while doing stuff in react, and it's hell to try and track down where the problem is. Does anyone have tips for digging through your UI to find these cases?

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `Constructor`. See https://..... /react-warning-keys for more information.
```

I've started just adding `key={Math.random}` to divs - is there any reason NOT to do this? React just needs any unique key?

If this is the case, I'm not sure why the framework doesn't just do that internally; they're already generating pseudonames for each of the DIVs it seems...

The error messages aren't very helpful in indicating where the problem is:

```
warning @ react-dev.js:18780validateExplicitKey @ react-dev.js:9316validateChildKeys @ react-dev.js:9378createElement @ react-dev.js:9483render @ Editor.tsx:245_renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext @ react-dev.js:5943_renderValidatedComponent @ react-dev.js:5963ReactCompositeComponent__renderValidatedComponent @ react-dev.js:12346_updateRenderedComponent @ react-dev.js:5916_performComponentUpdate @ react-dev.js:5900updateComponent @ react-dev.js:5829ReactCompositeComponent_updateComponent @ react-dev.js:12346performUpdateIfNecessary @ react-dev.js:5777performUpdateIfNecessary @ react-dev.js:13036runBatchedUpdates @ react-dev.js:13734perform @ react-dev.js:15623perform @ react-dev.js:15623perform @ react-dev.js:13691flushBatchedUpdates @ react-dev.js:13752ReactUpdates_flushBatchedUpdates @ react-dev.js:12346closeAll @ react-dev.js:15689perform @ react-dev.js:15636batchedUpdates @ react-dev.js:8455enqueueUpdate @ react-dev.js:13781enqueueUpdate @ react-dev.js:13371enqueueSetState @ react-dev.js:13537ReactComponent.setState @ react-dev.js:5204(anonymous function) @ Editor.tsx:100v @ zepto.min.js:2S.onreadystatechange @ zepto.min.js:2
OptionPicker.tsx:44template.initValue spot_intro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is called [reconcilliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) and it's explained in [react's Multiple Components doc page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children):

> When React reconciles the keyed children, it will ensure that any
>   child with key will be reordered (instead of clobbered) or destroyed
>   (instead of reused).

If you use `Math.random`, you'll get a different id every time so react won't be able to do its trick. [This very example](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1342#issuecomment-39230939) appeared in react's github issues and as Paul O’Shannessy pointed:

> - key is not really about performance, it's more about identity (which in turn leads to better performance). randomly assigned and changing
>     values are not identity
> - We can't realistically provide keys without knowing how your data is modeled. I would suggest maybe using some sort of hashing function if
>     you don't have ids
> - We already have internal keys when we use arrays, but they are the index in the array. When you insert a new element, those keys are
>     wrong.

I'd suggest you read the aforementioned thread.

Comment: yes, I've read it about it each time i have to track it down. The question was - how better to track it down, and what is stopping react from applying a unique key to each item itself?

Comment: thanks, thats a helpful discussion. I guess random keys don't solve the issue. Actually in the case where I *am* adding keys, I can't seem to see them appear in the DOM with the insepector. Do they get stripped away at some point?

Comment: You could say so, in Francesc Rosas words: "The key here is to understand not everything in the DOM has a representation in React Virtual DOM" on this very topic https://coderwall.com/p/jdybeq/the-importance-of-component-keys-in-react-js

Comment: thanks. is it true that a key only needs to be unique in the scope of the elements being iterated? so using an count/index is adequate? Or do they have to be globally unique over the whole SPA?

Comment: A scoped index is enough